# How do I detect a switch opening with an Arduino?

Tags: arduino

I have brought some Honeywell Actuv PIR (Passive InfraRed) detectors. I know that zone wire contacts become open circuit when it's triggered. How can I detect this using my Arduino?

Comment: Same way you would detect any other NC switch.

Comment: The question really has nothing to do with Honeywell or PIR sensors.

Comment: LOL Sorry I forgot it's just a bloody switch therefore I treat it as just a regular push switch. Dont know why I didn't think of that. Thanks guys. I only said Activ pir just to clarify it's not one of those 3pin pir modules which slightly different. For one they're not pet resistent

Answer (score 2):

**Just treat it as a normal push switch.**
If there's not already, you'll need to add a pull down resistor, since it's normally closed/ X voltage, but when pushed it is 0 volts, but there will be "static" left in it that your Arduino can't detect. (For a lack of a better explanation; just look up pull up/down resistors if you want to know more.)

**WARNING:** Nobody else has mentioned this before, so I've taken on the responsibility to do so. **Make sure that the switch is operating at less than 5V.** (3ish V or above for digital, but you should be able to get away with very little voltage with an analog pin.)

I don't know how isolated the switch is; you'll have to judge how the Arduino will affect the circuit and vice versa. Consider pull up/down resistors like I said. If you don't feel knowledgeable to do this, get advice. **It's better to ask advice and wait a day than to not get advice and have no Arduino.** (I speak from experience with many gadgets that I tried to rig, yet no Arduinos hurt actually... yet. Haha.)